# Instead of id name needs to be display spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application which saves and retrieves tasks. During the retrieval, I want to display student name instead of student id.
I have attached my current code below. This is what the response in Postman looks like this format.

```
  {
        "taskid": 4,
        "taskname": "taskkk",
        "description": "ssstaskkk",
        "complete": true,
        "studentId": 1
    }
```

TaskController

```
@GetMapping(path="/getAllTasks")
    public List<TaskDTO> getAllTasks()
    {
        List<TaskDTO> allTasks = taskService.getAllTasks();
        System.out.println(allTasks.size());
        System.out.println(allTasks);
        return allTasks;
    }
```

**TaskService**

```
  List<TaskDTO> getAllTasks();
```

**TaskServiceIMPL**

```
@Override
public List<TaskDTO> getAllTasks() {


    List<Task> getTasks = taskRepo.findAll();

    System.out.println(getTasks);

    List<TaskDTO> taskDTOList = new ArrayList<>();

    for(Task t:getTasks)
    {
        TaskDTO taskDTO = new TaskDTO(
                t.getTaskid(),
                t.getTaskname(),
                t.getDescription(),
                 t.getComplete(),
                t.getStudent().getStudentid()
        );
        taskDTOList.add(taskDTO);
    }
    return taskDTOList;
}
```

**Task**

```
public class Task {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "task_id", length = 50)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long taskid;

    @Column(name = "task_name")
    private String taskname;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "complete")
    private Boolean complete;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_id")
    private Student student;
}
```

**TaskRepo**

```
public interface TaskRepo extends JpaRepository<Task,Long >
{

}
```

Student Entity

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy =GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="student_id", length = 50)
private Long  studentid;

@Column(name="student_name", length = 50)
private String studentname;

@Column(name="address", length = 70)
private String address;

@Column(name="mobile", length = 12)
private int mobile;

@Column(name="activestate", columnDefinition = "TINYINT default 1")
private boolean activestate;
```

Student DTO

```
public class StudentDTO {
    private Long studentid;
    private String studentname;
    private String address;
    private int mobile;
    private boolean activestate;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From you TaskController, you are returning a list of TaskDTO objects.
In order to display student names, you need to add StudentDTO class inside your TaskDTO class. Your TaskDTO class should be like below:

Modified **TaskDTO**:

```
public class TaskDTO {
    private Long taskid;
    private String taskname;
    private String description;
    private Boolean complete;
    private StudentDTO student; // Use StudentDTO here along 
                                  with it's constructor,getters,setters.
}
```

Now, you need to update your TaskServiceIMPL to create TaskDTO objects with StudentDTO.

Modified **TaskServiceIMPL**:

```
@Override
public List<TaskDTO> getAllTasks() {
    List<Task> getTasks = taskRepo.findAll();

    List<TaskDTO> taskDTOList = new ArrayList<>();

    for(Task t : getTasks) {
        Student student = t.getStudent(); // Get the associated student
        StudentDTO studentDTO = new StudentDTO(
            student.getStudentid(),
            student.getStudentname(),
            student.getAddress(),
            student.getMobile(),
            student.isActivestate()
        );
        
        TaskDTO taskDTO = new TaskDTO(
            t.getTaskid(),
            t.getTaskname(),
            t.getDescription(),
            t.getComplete(),
            studentDTO // Set the StudentDTO object here
        );
        
        taskDTOList.add(taskDTO);
    }
    return taskDTOList;
}
```

Now, your **TaskController** should return the modified **TaskDTO**

Comment: i modified program as you said  "taskid": null,
        "taskname": null,
        "description": null,
        "complete": null,
        "studentId": 0,
        "student": null

Comment: make sure that the Student entity's fields are being fetched correctly. If any field of the Student entity is null or not properly populated, it will reflect in the DTO as well.

Comment: [TaskDTO(taskid=null, taskname=null, description=null, complete=null, studentId=0, student=null), TaskDTO(taskid=null, taskname=null, description=null, complete=null, studentId=0, student=null)]

Comment: i checked on console as well is there any way to write the join query in TaskRepo bro

Comment: Yes, you can you custom query in your TaskRepo interface using @Query annotation and JPQL, something like below:


```public interface TaskRepo extends JpaRepository<Task, Long> {
   @Query("SELECT NEW com.example.TaskDTO(t.taskid, t.taskname, t.description, t.complete, s.studentname) FROM Task t JOIN t.student s")
   List<TaskDTO> findAllTasksWithStudentName();
}```



for more understanding, you can search on youtube with JPQL query
You can upvote my answers to help me and also reach others if you think my answer and comments were helpful to you.

Comment: @Query(value="select s.student_id, s.student_name, t.taskname from student s Inner JOIN task t ON s.student_id=t.student_id", nativeQuery=true)
    List<Object[]> findStudent();

Comment: but i wrote so how to call it

Comment: In your service or controller, inject the TaskRepo and call the findStudent() method.
    ``@GetMapping("/student-tasks")
    public List<Object[]> getStudentTasks() {
        return taskRepo.findStudent();
    }``

Comment: t.getStudent().getStudentname()  i wrote it getting error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254868/discussion-between-john-peter-and-mohammad-nayem).